# v-form and v-text-field not working in vue cli 3.0

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I'm currently creating a project using Vue Cli 3. And for its UI, I chose to use Vuetify. In adding Vuetify to Vue Cli 3, I simply ran the command

```
vue add vuetify
```

I can use other features of Vuetify like `v-layout`, `v-button`, etc. But whenever I'm using `v-form` or `v-text-field`, it seems to be not working. And the error is:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

Can someone help me so I can make these things work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which version of vuetify are you using? Could you share a code snippet where you are using v-text-field? It is working for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/vqm5m8lwz0

Comment: The [vue-cli-plugin-vuetify](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify) doesn't look very polished. I'd just install vuetify in your project the old-fashioned way

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me too. It seems like an importation problem. I solved it importing vuetify css file at my `main.js` file. Like:

```
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you choose "Use a-la-carte components" during the installation process of vue-cli-plugin-vuetify? If so, make sure that you also have imported and added all necessary components to the configuration file **plugins/vuetify.js**

Add the names of your needed components to the import statement.

```
import { 
  Vuetify, 
  VApp,
  ...,
  VForm,
  VTextField,
  ...
} from 'vuetify';
```

And make sure you also add your imported components to the components section where vuetify gets initalized.

```
Vue.use(Vuetify,{
components: {
VApp,
...,
VForm
VTextField,
...
}})
```

Further information: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/guides/a-la-carte